# Cayenne Query Expression -- Need clarification

Tags: sql, apache-cayenne

In the Apache Cayenne documentation, they provide an example of how to create a parameterized query using the Expression class' fromString() function:

```
// create a qualifier with two named parameters: "pname" and "aname"
Expression qual = Expression.fromString("paintingTitle = $pname or toArtist.artistName = $aname");

// build a query prototype of a query - simply another select query
SelectQuery proto = new SelectQuery(Painting.class, qual);
```

The making of such a query is pretty straightforward, except for one problem: the documentation does not explain what $pname and $aname are or how to set them to the values you want to query for!

Can anyone explain how to set these parameters??? Please advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably checking older documentation. Check out "Named Parameter Expressions" [here](http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.0/building-expressions.html) if you are on Cayenne 3.0, or "Creating Expressions from Strings" [here](http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.1/cayenne-guide/expressions.html#expressions-from-strings) for 3.1. But in any event, this is fairly simple - you put your parameters in a Map, and then use "expWithParameters" method. To follow your example:

```
Expression qual = 
   Expression.fromString("paintingTitle = $pname or toArtist.artistName = $aname");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("pname", "A");
params.put("aname", "B");

qual = qual.expWithParameters(params);
```

Note that in the last line I am reassigning the Expression, as 'expWithParameters' creates a clone.